# Flexbox and safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox

So I'm running into issues with safari.  It seems like both in ios and on macs flexbox is not working for me, even though it should.

When I view it on ios, the boxes are displayed inline, though they should be displayed as block.

When I view it in safari on my desktop (PC), it displays as block, but it's supposed to be inline.

It works perfectly in chrome.

Here's the HTML:

```
            <div class="flex-parent" style="margin:10px;margin-top: 30px;padding: 15px;border: 2px solid #EEEEEE;">
            <div style="width: 100%;"><h2><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1); text-align:center;">Why?</span></h2></div>
            <div class="flex-2"><ul class="front-page-list" style="list-style-type:none;margin-top:-20px;">
                <li>
            <h3><span style="color:red;font-size: 30px;margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span style="color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1)">Because flexbox is new</span></h3>
            </li>
                <li>
            <h3><span style="color:red;font-size: 30px;margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span style="color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1)">Apple likes to make everyone work around them</span></h3>
            </li>
                <li>
            <h3><span style="color:red;font-size: 30px;margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span style="color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1)">There are too many versions of ios</span></h3>
            </li>
                <li>
            <h3><span style="color:red;font-size: 30px;margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span style="color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1)">I'm not very good at this yet</span></h3>
            </li>
                <li>
            <h3><span style="color:red;font-size: 30px;margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span style="color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1)">Etc.</span></h3>
            </li>
                <li>
            <h3><span style="color:red;font-size: 30px;margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span><span style="color: rgba(1, 61, 121, 1)">Etc.</span></h3>
            </li>
            </ul></div><div class="flex-2">
            <img src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/e1441825407759.jpg"  height="100%" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-422" />
            </div></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
            .flex-parent{
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                max-width: 1100px;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: stretch;

            }

            .flex-2{
                width:40%;
                min-width: 400px;
                flex-grow: 1;
                margin:2%;
                padding: 0;
            }
```

And here is what it has morphed into as I've gotten progressively more frustrated and desperate:

```
            .flex-parent{
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-direction:row;
                flex-direction: row;
                -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                max-width: 1000px;
                -webkit-align-items: center;
                align-items: center;
                -webkit-justify-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
                -webkit-align-content: stretch;
                align-content: stretch;

            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 600){
            .flex-parent{
            display: block;
            }
            .flex-2{
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            }

            }
            .flex-2{
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex-box;
                -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                width:40%;
                min-width: 300px;
                -webkit-flex: 1;
                flex-grow: 1;
                margin:1%;
                padding: 0;
            }
```

None of it is working... if anything I'm getting further away.  I'm not sure what to do other than start a petition on change.org to make outdated browsers illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the webkit handler for each of the flex properties. No need to add anything else. See the pen and corresponding code below. Works for me in Safari (layout is identical to the one in Chrome).
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaMzqr?editors=110

```
.flex-parent {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   max-width: 1100px;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   -webkit-align-content: stretch;
   align-content: stretch;
 }

 .flex-2 {
   width: 40%;
   min-width: 400px;
   -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
   flex-grow: 1;
   margin: 2%;
   padding: 0;
 }
```